# Cannot set windows 7 password after log-in with KonBoot

Tags: windows, passwords

I recently forgot my windows 7 password, and used KonBoot to bypass it. 
I booted my computer with Hirens Boot CD, and from the menu options - I selected "Password Recovery tools".  After Selecting "Kon-Boot" - I am now able to login to my pc, however cannot create a password for my admin user.

I tried "create password for this account", but once I typed in new password, it says" password incorrect", and wont allow me to set a password.

I tried creating a new admin user, and setting a password for it, but you can still login to the new admin account with any password, even by just pressing enter.

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated please.

Comment: Just remove KonBoot.

Comment: @SLaks I used it from a boot disk (Hiren's boot disk). I did not install it.  I have also since removed the disk and rebooted, but nothing works :(

Comment: Try running the `sfc /scannow` in an elevated Command Prompt

Comment: @JamesYoung Thank you very much. That did the trick :)

Comment: @user1426583 I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `sfc /scannow` in an elevated Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Kon-Boot affects only the `sethc.exe` file in the `System32`
and `SysWOW…` folders. 
You have to copy a `sethc.exe` from another Windows machine, and install it into yours (in those folders I mentioned above).

After a restart, the last username and password that you had in use will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Konboot only bypasses checks for login. You can use the command prompt to set passwords with the following command.

```
net user USERNAME NEWPASSWORD
```

note that the old password is not needed.